# Eclipse MAT find memory leak

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-leaks

I have an object in Android that is not garbage collecting. It is under the package com.test.game.GameScene. Is there a way in the eclipse plugin MAT that I can find the reference that is keeping this object from garbage collecting? I know it is something in histogram, but I  don't see any objects or anything that I created in it. Or at least anything that I can recognize from my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it is in the histogram and basically its just a series of right clicking and using the incoming reference.